# Can't get simple product (min) Price Wordpress Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

hello guys I'm trying to get create a function to get the product has the most min & max Price in the woocommerce query.
problem is my query not get the lowest product that has price

**here example of products:**

1. 200 USD
2. 300 USD ON SALE
3. 400 USD
4. 500 USD
5. 600 USD

and the result is the product with 400 USD, and it must be 200 not 400.

my query :

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'ignore_stickie_posts' => true,
  'fields' => 'ids',
  'orderby' => 'price',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  
  );
 $products_price_min_args = get_posts($args);

$string_id = implode(",", $products_price_min_args);
$product = wc_get_product( $string_id );

if($product) {
  if ( $product->is_type('variable') ){
    $price_min = $product->get_variation_price('min'); // Float number
  }
  elseif ( $product->is_type('simple') ){
    if( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
      $price_min = $product->get_sale_price();         
    }
    else{
      $price_min = $product->get_price(); 
    }
  }
  return $price_min;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Woocommerce product prices are stored in this table - wp_wc_product_meta_lookup

So, you have to query the data from this table and get the min price. As you are using get_posts so it is getting the product from the default WordPress posts table where the price for the product isn't stored.

Here is the updated code to fetch the min price of the product from the posts meta table -

```
$args = array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'ignore_stickie_posts' => true,
      'fields' => 'ids',
    );
    
    $products = get_posts($args);
    
    $all_product_prices = array();
    
    foreach($products as $product_id) {
        
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        
        if ( $product->is_type('variable') ){
            $price_min = $product->get_variation_price('min'); // Float number
          }
          elseif ( $product->is_type('simple') ){
            if( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
              $price_min = $product->get_sale_price();         
            }
            else{
              $price_min = $product->get_price(); 
            }
          }
        
        array_push($all_product_prices, $price_min);
        
    }
    
    $price = min($all_product_prices);
    
    return $price;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering sir, that was helpfull, but is there any query else that i can use to get product price because i dont want to use sql query from table

Comment: It seems like the product prices are also stored in the default posts meta table of WordPress, so the data can be fetched directly from the posts meta table without using any SQL queries. I have updated your code a bit. You can use the code that I have provided above.